# Use object properties in LongListSelector (XAML)

Tags: .net, vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm trying to use the LongListSelector to show a list of notes in my WP8 application. I use a list of Note (Note is my object name) and Note has two properties : *Titre* and *Contenu*. Simply, I want to display the *Titre* property of my object in my LongListSelector. I have this code :
`ListeNotes.ItemsSource = ListNotes`

(because ListNotes is my List's name and ListeNotes is my LongListSelector's name). But it shows a list containing only CloudyNote.Note the number of time I have notes. How could I do to show the *Title* property instead of the object name in my LongListSelector ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define ItemTemplate specifying which property to display :

```
<phone:LongListSelector>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titre}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

    ...

<phone:LongListSelector/>
```